# Adding custom form type in Activiti 5.17

Tags: forms, types, custom-post-type, activiti

I'm working with activiti explorer, and i have some questions with adding a custom form type.

In particular i want to create a comboBox that fills up with data from a database (PostgreSQL), and i'm following this post:
http://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/2013/03/13/creating-a-new-form-property-in-activiti/

The thing is that in the last version of activiti (5.17) the file activiti-custom-context.xml comes all commented, and when i uncomment all the code that comes by default and to the deploy the war in tomcat it crashes.

All the posts that i see says that this is very easy, and to me it's taiking me more than 2 weeks.

Please, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 5.16.2 and beyond, activiti-custom-context.xml is used to supplement the primary configuration classes that use spring annotations. While you can use the XML file, I would recommend you simply update the ActivitiEngineConfiguration class directly. You will need to add a new form type and an associated form renderer for the type. Register the form type in the configuration. If you need a custom parser (which it sounds like you will) then create a custom form parser that extends org.activiti.engine.impl.form.FormTypes and register this in the configuration as well.
That;s the good news, now for the bad news. Other than the variable that is bound to the form control, the form renderer doesnt have access to the execution context (including task id, execution id etc) so you cannot reference the context. So, you will need to do the database lookup in the form element renderer. I would use a helper bean for the DB lookup and query so you have some ability to externalize the DB connection and query.